# Object type to use in RCPP for S7 object?

Tags: r, oop, rcpp

I'm writing a routine to close an SPI connection.

**My Question:** how do I declare an R7 (or S7) object for RCPP?

I've set this connection up as an R7 (S7) object. Here's the class definition

```
[r code]
spi <- new_class("spi",
  properties = list(
      spiChan = class_integer,
      spiBus = class_integer,
      max_speed_hz = new_property(class_integer, default = "???defaultvalue???"),
      spiDeviceID = new_property(class_integer, default = "#rpi_spi_open")
      )
)
```

Then I declare a class - nothing new here.

```
[R code]
mcp3008 <- spi(spiChan = 0, spiBus=0)
```

I'd like to pass that object to a c++ function. Something like this...

```
[c++]
int spi_close(S7 x) {
   close(x@spiDeviceID)
}
```

So that I can do this...

```
[R]
close(mcp3008)
```

In the c++ code above I've declared an S7 object. But should I be calling it a `List` or `S3` or `S4`

Thanks!
MNR

Comment: You tell us!  I am not sure anybody in Team Rcpp has had much exposure to S7 yet.  Also see https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1283

Comment: Also, and always a classic. we have been spelling it `Rcpp`.  Upper-case R, lower-case cpp.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! Sorry about the RCPP/Rcpp. As to List vs S3/S4/S7, I'd guess it should eventually be S7 for consistency. But I'm an innocent bystander on this one. Let me take a look and see If I can wrangle a PR for github